# Listening and handling Java Events without UIs

Tags: java, events, listeners, handlers

I'm working on a Java project which requires we be on the lookout for changing events in the system. However, many of these events are on the back-end and can constantly change, and such they aren't looking for any button input.
Every example of event handlers and listeners I've researched seems to involve a GUI, however; is it possible to do this without a GUI component to attach handlers and listeners to?

Comment: Yes, for example the observer pattern is very often used for this (but listeners can be used, too).

Answer (score 1):

You can try `java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport` which lets you register `java.beans.PropertyChangeListener`s. A change will be indicated via a call to `firePropertyChange`.